# How do I prevent Visual SourceSafe from writing the vssver2.scc file when getting a file with Microsoft.VisualStudio.SourceSafe.Interop?

Tags: c#, visual-sourcesafe

I get a file from Visual SourceSafe using the below code:

```
IVSSItem vssFile = vssDataBase.get_VSSItem(vssFilePath + @"/" + fileName, false);

VSSItem itemVer = vssFile.get_Version(latestVersionNumber);
itemVer.Get(ref getFilePath, (int)VSSFlags.VSSFLAG_FORCEDIRNO | (int)VSSFlags.VSSFLAG_REPREPLACE | (int)VSSFlags.VSSFLAG_USERRONO);
```

Visual SourceSafe adds a vssver2.scc file to each folder. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

I've tried various combinations of the [VSSFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.sourcesafe.interop.vssflags%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) enum with no luck. I don't need to preserve any history and the file will never be checked back in. I just want a clean checkout.

Obligatory disclaimer: I can't switch to another source control program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized my interest in getting files cleanly via SourceSafe.Interop was more aesthetic than practical. I'm still interested in a solution but I ended up doing this after all the files were checked out.

```
foreach (FileInfo visualSourceSafeFile in testDirectoryInfo.GetFiles("*.scc", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    visualSourceSafeFile.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
    visualSourceSafeFile.Delete();
}
```

If you don't change the file attribute to Normal before you delete, you'll probably run into exceptions. Visual SourceSafe marks them as Hidden, System, and ReadOnly.

Comment: When I do a GetFiles( "*.scc", SearchOption.AllDirectories ) it doesn't return the *.scc files.  Even GetFiles( "*.*" ) doesn't show them.  Any ideas?

Comment: You need to add an asterisk (\*) before the .scc, i.e. "*.scc".

Comment: I had.  Figured out my problem.  I hadn't 'closed' the VSS database connection so it hadn't written out the *.scc files.